# Назначение метода toString()

Tags: java

Для чего предназначен метод `toString()` в Java и в каких случаях его нужно переопределять?

Comment: чтобы реализовать свои детские фантазии

Comment: Что бы реализовать текстовое представление вашего обьекта для рендеринга. Например можно создать обьект простая дробь, а в toString зашить вывод `1/2`

Answer (score 5):

Для общего экземпляра класса метод `toString()` возвращает имя класса объекта и его хэшкод. Если для вашего класса необходимо, чтобы его представление в виде строки было более содержательным, этот метод может быть переопределен.

Например, у вас есть некий класс хранящий информацию о пользователе. Вы можете переопределить метод `toString()`, чтобы при выводе этого класса на экран ( `System.out.print (someUser);`) вместо нелепой строки, вроде *User@4867856* были его имя и фамилия.

Так же можно переопредилить этот метод и для классов API, в которых он уже повторно переопределен, чтобы изменить то, что выводится на экран при "печати" этого класса, если это нужно в вашей программе. Например, для `Integer` вместо просто вывода числа, выводить *целое 1* (пример утрирован)

Некоторый [пример](http://www.it-rem.ru/java-testiruem-metod-tostring.html)

Comment: В дополнение к ответу, если вы работаете в IDEA, можете генерировать этот метод средствами IDE. `Generate` (Alt+Insert) -> `toString()`

Answer (score 2):

В [API specification java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) дано неплохое определение:

> In general, the toString method returns a string that "textually
>   represents" this object. The result should be a concise but
>   informative representation that is easy for a person to read.

Метод `toString` возвращает "текстовое предоставление" объекта в таком виде, что бы было понятно для человека.

Метод желательно переопределять для всех создаваемых программистом классов с целью повышения информативности логов. Но в большинстве случаев разработчики ограничиваются только теми классами, которые регулярно попадают в лог. Про переопределение метода `toString` более подробно можно почитать в книге «Эффективное программирование» - Джошуа Блоха этому вопросу посвящена 10я статья 3й главы.

Comment: Вопрос автора заключался в том, зачем нужно его переопределять.