# Почему при выводе элемента ArrayList'а на экран выводится UserName@cac736f?

Tags: java, arraylist

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: при выводе одного элемента списка, используя метод `get()`, выводится `UserName@cac736f`, вместо данных, которые находятся в этом списке. Но когда через цикл вывожу данные из этого же списка, только уже все, то все окей.

С чем это может быть связано?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StartRegistor {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ArrayList<UserName> userList = new ArrayList<>();
        userList.add(new UserName("Tikhon","qwerty"));
        for (UserName UserName: userList) {
            System.out.println("Name: "+ UserName.name +", password: " +UserName.password);
        }
        System.out.println(userList.get(0));
    }
}
    
class UserName{
     String name;
     String password;
        
     UserName(String name, String password){
         this.name =  name;
         this.password = password;
       }
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Назначение метода toString()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/592316/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-tostring)

Comment: Вам нужно переопределить метод `toString` в своём классе `UserName`, чтобы вывод выглядел корректно; в цикле вы выводите информацию по каждому полю отдельно.

Answer (score 1):

Почему это происходит? Потому что все классы (в том числе и ваш) наследуются по умолчанию от класса `Object`. А в этом классе есть метод `toString()`, который неявно вызывается при выводе чего-либо на экран и в данном случае выводит кеш-код объекта (у вас `ArrayList` с объектами!). Фактически, вы пытаетесь сделать что-то подобное:

```
public class Test{
  public static void main(String[]args){
     Test t = new Test();
     System.out.println(t);
  }
}
```

Чтобы вывод был правильным, переопределите метод `toString()` в классе `UserName`:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
  return "Name: "+ name +", password: " + password;
}
```

Теперь при попытке вывести объект класса `UserName` на экран (что вы и делали) будет выводиться имя и пароль пользователя.